# How can I mock an ObjectMetadata object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, powermock

I have the below method:

```
private boolean success(String key) {
    if (cachedStatus.containsKey(key)) {
      return cachedJobsStatus.get(key).booleanValue();
    }
    String status = String.format("%s/%s", key, SUCCESS);
    ObjectMetadata meta = getMetadata(key);
    Boolean isOK = Boolean.FALSE;
    if (meta != null) {
      isOK = Boolean.TRUE;
   }
    cachedStatus.put(objectKey, isOK);
    return isOK.booleanValue();
}
```

I created this test:

```
public void successTest() throws Exception {
    String key = "data1-1-33-a.txt/part-00002-attempt_201711232056_0000_m_000002_2";

    //test when _SUCCESS exists
    boolean result = Whitebox.invokeMethod(APIClient, "success", key);
    Assert.assertEquals("successuccessful() failed even when _SUCCESS exists",
        true, result);
```

I believe the test is failing because meta never exists so isOK doesn't get set to true.

To get the test working properly I think I must create a mock for meta but I'm not sure how. Can anybody please advice?

This is the getMetadata() method:

```
protected ObjectMetadata getMetadata(String key) {
    try {
      ObjectMetadata m = client.getMetadata(bucket, key);
      return m;
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
      LOG.warn(e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `getMetadata()` method definition?

Comment: Apologies. I added it to my question.

Comment: Ok, so `ObjectMetadata` is created by invoking `client.getMetadata(bucket, key)` but - based on the code you have supplied - I have no idea what `client` or `bucket` are. I suspect this question is easily answered (inject a mocked `client` and set an expectation on it to return a mocked `ObjectMetadata` when `getMetadata` is invoked ...) but without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I couldn't be more specific.

Comment: client is an AmazonS3 client and bucket is the bucket. I've set `Whitebox.setInternalState(APIClient, "bucket", bucketName);` where `String bucketName = "aa-bb-cc";`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most easy way would be to mock your `client`.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

   @Mock
   private AmazonS3Client client;   // or whatever

   @Mock
   private ObjectMetadata mockedObjectMetadata;

   @InjectMocks
   private MyClassToTest toTest; // Put your class that has "client" here

   @Test
   public void someTest() {
       Mockit.when(client.getMetadata(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn( mockedObjectMetadata ); // voila

       boolean result = toTest("someRandomKey");
       ///etc.
   }

}
```

Comment: Great. Unfortunately, that information alone is not helpful. Make it easier to help you by providing more information.

Comment: OK, what information should I provide? The stack trace points to this lise in my method under test: `ObjectMetadata meta = getMetadata(key);`

Comment: Strange, since literally nothing in that line could produce a NullPointerException...